# Копирование самого себя Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Как реализовать?

При запуске программа делает копию себя на диск C:
а если программа уже скопирована на диск С:
то не копировать.

Comment: А проблема-то в чем? GetFileAttributes + CopyFile и какбэ все.

Comment: пример кода можно?

Comment: "Пример" это будет написать все за вас, а я за такую работу деньги получаю. Примеры использования упомянутых API функций определенно есть в MSDN.

Comment: Сейчас это делается с помощью `<filesystem>`

Answer (score 3):

Вирусы пишем?)

```
BOOL WINAPI CopyFile(LPCTSTR fromName, LPCTSTR toName, BOOL failIfExists);
```

> Если failIfExists установлен в TRUE, то при условии, что файл с именем
>   toName уже существует, то функция завершится ошибкой. В противном
>   случае (failIfExists = FALSE) имеющийся файл toName будет перезаписан.

Т.е. функция возвращает результат операции (если хочется знать есть ли файл уже).

[Источник](http://rsdn.ru/article/qna/baseserv/fileop.xml)

Comment: Функция может вернуть ошибку и если нет прав на запись, так что причину ошибки лучше через GetLastError получать. Или предварительно определять наличие целевого файла.